# how to prove $\int_{0}^{l}f(x)dx \leq 0$

Tags: calculus

If $$\int_{0}^{l}f(x)xdx=0$$

Is $$\int_{0}^{l}f(x)dx \leq 0$$ true?
If it is true,how to prove it?

Where l>0, and f(0)=f(x)=0.

Comment: Be careful with your statement $f(0) = f(x) = 0$. You most likely mean $f(0) = f(l) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say no. There seems to be a counterexample.

Let f(x) = sin(x)/x. And let l = 2π. Then

$\int_0^lf(x)xdx$

becomes

$\int_0^{2π}(sin(x)/x)xdx$

which is  $\int_0^{2π}sin(x)dx$ which is 0.

However $\int_0^lf(x)dx$ becomes $\int_0^{2π}(sin(x)/x)dx$ which is greater than 0.

But take my answer with a grain of salt. It's been awhile since I've done any integral calculus.

Comment: No reason, it is a perfectly fine answer.